Using integration to find the volume of a sphere whose centre is at origin.
The equation of a circle whose center is at its origin is:
$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$   ($r$ means radius)
Hence:
$$y^2=r^2-x^2 \implies y= \sqrt {r^2-x^2}$$
Hence:
$f(x) =  \sqrt {r^2-x^2}$
How can I integrate $f(x)$ for $r=0 \to r=r$
to get the volume $\frac43 \pi r^3$?

Welcome to Math SE. The question you posted can be found in any calculus textbook.

This question is similar to: Prove that volume of a sphere with radius $r$ is $V=\frac43r^3\pi$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. This was found using a site search. Not there are also many other duplicates, & near duplicates, ...

(cont.) on this site, with those search results including quite a few of them. Finally, welcome to Math SE.

We will use disk integration method i.e.,  $V=\int_{a}^b A(y)dy$ when rotated about x axis. Here A(y) is cross-sectional area when sliced through y axis.

Here by Pythagoras theorem we get that $y=\sqrt {r^2-x^2}$. So $A(y)=\pi y^2= \pi (r^2-x^2)$
Therefore $V= \int_{-r}^r \pi (r^2-x^2)dx= |\pi (r^2x-\frac{x^3}{3})|_{-r} ^r$
This will give $\pi ((r^2*r-\frac{r^3}{3})-((-r)r^2-\frac{-r^3}{3}) = 2\pi (r^3-\frac{r^3}{3})= \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$
Therefore volume of sphere is $ \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$
